# Make Compiler's Implicit Data Type Conversions Explicit

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion, decompiling

I'm working with a large `VB.NET` code base. The project is set to have [Option Strict Off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). This means that data type conversions take place implicitly.

I am looking to change the project to have `Option Strict On`. To satisfy the compiler, all type conversions will now have to be made explicitly. However, with the goal of functional equivalency, I'd like to take all the conversions the compiler would do when `Option Strict Off` and make them explicit in my source code. Rather than do this manually, I'm wondering whether there's a tool I can use which would help me do this automatically?

I've tried using a decompiler, but this doesn't seem to work for me since I've found cases where the `IL` doesn't lend itself to `VB`.

Comment: Option Strict Off gives you late binding. IOW, the compiler doesn't do the type conversions, they happen at runtime..

Comment: That's only part of it. When `Option Strict Off`, a statement such as `Dim x As Integer = "1"` involves a compile-time conversion.

Comment: OK. For those, I don't know of a product to help, but I would look into Resharper et al.